# Detect and count the number of people in an image using matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

Counting the number of people in a room using **MatLab** but couldn't do it accurately using Viola-Jones Algorithm. can someone help me out, please?

```
%Detect objects using Viola-Jones Algorithm

%% CODE FOR PEOPLE COUNT BASED ON FACES
%get the input image

I=imread('DCN.jpg')*2;

imshow(I),title('Image:1'); 


J = rgb2gray(I);

%To detect Face

FDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;


% Returns Bounding Box values based on number of objects

BB = step(FDetect,J);

figure,

%detectedImg = insertObjectAnnotation(J,'rectangle',BB,'stop sign');

%
imshow(J); hold on

for i = 1:size(BB,1)

    rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','y');
end

title('Face Detection');
hold off;

numberOfBlobs = length(BB);

message = sprintf('Done by  Abhishek.\nThe number of persons = %d', numberOfBlobs);

uiwait(helpdlg(message));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another well known algorithm for pedestrian detection using HOG an svm.
Look at the following tutorial for Matlab.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.peopledetector-class.html

Comment: the link no longer exists.